# Python: What am I doing wrong? (Ties in Python Functions)

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, tuples

I have a list of number of work hours of some employees in a month in the form of tuples and I would like to choose the employee of the month based on the highest number of work hours in the month. But what if we have some tuples with ties between them? How will the function change as I want to include both the employees who had tie between them.

Here's what I've got too far.

```py
work_hours = [("Abby",400),("Billy",500),("Cassie",700),("David",700)]

def employee_check(work_hours):

    current_max_hours = 0           
    employee_of_the_month = ""
    
    for a,b in work_hours:
        if b >= current_max_hours:
            employee_of_the_month = a
            current_max_hours = b
        
        else:
            pass
    
    return (employee_of_the_month,current_max_hours)

employee_check(work_hours)
```

Then I'm getting the last one as my output.

```py
('David', 700)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only storing one employee as the employee of the month, even when there is a tie. You need to modify your code to store multiple employees in case of a tie.

```
def employee_check(work_hours: list[tuple[str, int]]) -> tuple[list[str], int]:
    """
    Determines the employee(s) with the highest number of work hours in a month.
    
    :param work_hours: List of tuples containing employee names and their corresponding work hours.
    
    :return: A tuple containing a list of employee(s) of the month and the highest number of work hours.
    """
    current_max_hours = 0
    employees_of_the_month = []
    for employee, hours in work_hours:
        if hours > current_max_hours:
            employees_of_the_month = [employee]
            current_max_hours = hours
        elif hours == current_max_hours:
            employees_of_the_month.append(employee)
    return (employees_of_the_month, current_max_hours)

work_hours = [("Abby", 400), ("Billy", 500), ("Cassie", 700), ("David", 700)]
print(employee_check(work_hours))
```

**Output:**

```
(['Cassie', 'David'], 700)
```

As you can see from the above output, the function will now return a list of employees of the month along with the highest number of work hours.

Comment: It works, but why go through all the trouble of a for loop instead of using the functions built in numpy or pandas? Less code, more readable, no need to reinvent the wheel, ad also vectorised code, which will be faster on large datasets

Comment: Actually I am new to python and my course has not yet reached that library thing. So I don't know any of that because it has just been a week or two since I started learning python.

Comment: @Abstract I know, which is why I tried to explain these things in my answer. This question was meant more for Sash Sinha who provided this answer

Comment: I used to modify OP code a lot but realized that I did not get the ✅ from OPs since OPs generally want their code fixed, not completely different.

Answer (score 1):

### Solutions which return only one result

If only one item has the maximum value, you could use `idxmax` in `pandas` or `argmax` in `numpy`
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

I know this is not your case, but, since you seem new to Python, I mention these methods as you might want to familiarise yourself with them for other cases.

### Building a solution with numpy and/or pandas

The solution below uses numpy. I show you how you can apply it to data stored in a pandas dataframe, or to data already in a numpy array:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# If the data is already in a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['Abbie','Billy','Cassie','David'], data=[400,500,700,700], columns=['hours'])


# With numpy
my_array = df['hours'].to_numpy()
my_max = np.max(my_array)
my_idx = np.argwhere(my_array == my_max).flatten()
# flatten converts it from a 2x1 array to a 2-array (ie from 2 dimensions to 1)

# Note that iloc uses position-based indices, not label-based.
print(df.iloc[my_idx,])
```

The output is:

```
        hours
Cassie    700
David     700
```

Note that the output is a pandas DataFrame with, in this case, just one column, so it could well be converted to a Series. I left it as a DataFrame because there may be cases where you have other columns which you may want to keep.

### Converting from tuple to numpy arrays or pandas dataframes

If the data is in a tuple, you can convert it to numpy arrays or dataframes as follows:

```
# If the data is in a tuple
work_hours = [("Abby",400),("Billy",500),("Cassie",700),("David",700)]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(work_hours), columns=['employee','hours'])
# up to you if you want to make the employee the index
```

### General comments

As a general rule, in interpreted languages like Python or R you should try to vectorise your code and to avoid loops when possible. If you are not familiar with the concept, look it up.

When a loop is unavoidable, numba https://numba.pydata.org/ can work wonders in speeding up your code. Obviously in this small example it doesn't make a difference, but keep it in mind for more computational-intensive tasks.

Other concepts with which, as a beginner, you may want to familiarise yourself:

- numpy.flatten() and the difference between a 2x1 array (2 dimensions) vs a 2-element array (one dimension)
- the difference between iloc and loc in pandas. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html
- chained assignments and returning a view vs a copy. This can be very confusing for newbies or for people coming from other languages https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

The last point is crucial.If you run

```
out = df.iloc[my_idx,]
out.loc['David','hours'] = 800
```

It works, but you will get

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  out.loc['David','hours'] = 800
```

One way of getting round that is explicitly creating a copy of the slice of the dataframe which you are returning:

```
import copy
out = copy.copy(df.iloc[my_idx,])
out.loc['David','hours'] = 800
```

Answer (score -1):

The comparison you are making is that the `current_max_hours` variable will be replaced if the `b` variable is GREATER or EQUAL to it, so obviously if the last item in the list has a value equal to the value of the item before it, it will replace the current value.

In this case the current order of the list is ("Cassie",700) -> ("David",700), 700 >= 700? Yes, so Cassie is replaced by David.

A possible solution is to use `sorted` to organize the list according to who has the most hours and then only display what has the most.

```py
work_hours = [("Abby",400), ("Billy",500), ("Cassie",700), ("David",700)]

def employee_check(work_hours: list[tuple[str, int]]) -> list[tuple[str, int]]:
    sorted_work_hours = sorted(work_hours, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    employees_of_the_month = []
    for worker, hours in sorted_work_hours:
        if hours == sorted_work_hours[0][1]:
            employees_of_the_month.append((worker, hours))
    return employees_of_the_month

print(employee_check(work_hours))
```

Output:

```bash
[('Cassie', 700), ('David', 700)]
```

Comment: This is O(N log N) because of the sort, but the problem can easily be solved in O(N) time.

Comment: @slothrop Since the OP is a newbie, it would be great if you could elaborate, as that's a very important point for a beginner to understand

Comment: OK, so compare for example with @SashSinha 's example. You can see that in that code, the loop iterates over every item in `work_hours` exactly once. So the "amount of work done" (loosely speaking) by the computer is linearly proportional to N, where N is the number of items in `work_hours`. But the work involved in *sorting* `work_hours` grows faster than a linear relationship to N: in fact it's proportional to (N * logarithm(N)). So especially for a large dataset, it's preferable to use algorithms that can iterate once over the dataset without sorting it.

Comment: You're right, I wanted to give another perspective and ended up not thinking about it, I ended up relying on the literal code of the question and didn't realize that this could (and maybe even will be) applied on a larger scale.